# How to fill area under a geom_line() plot with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to fill the area below and above the two lines that are plotted through ggplot.
These are the data points that are plotted:

```
polygon_data <- data.frame(checkpoints=c(650,1625,3250,650,1625,3250), lower=c(-1.17,0.20,1.36,-Inf,-Inf,-Inf), upper=c(2.28,1.75,1.36,Inf,Inf,Inf))
checkpoints_data <- data.frame(checkpoints=c(650,1625,3250),design.lower.bound=c(-1.17,0.20,1.36),design.upper.bound=c(2.28,1.75,1.36))


ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data=polygon_data,mapping=aes(x=checkpoints, y=lower, fill="red", alpha=0.8))+
  geom_polygon(data=polygon_data,mapping=aes(x=checkpoints, y=upper, fill="green", alpha=0.8))+
  geom_line(checkpoints_data,mapping= aes(x=checkpoints, y=design.upper.bound))+
  geom_line(checkpoints_data,mapping= aes(x=checkpoints, y=design.lower.bound))+
  geom_point(checkpoints_data,mapping= aes(x=checkpoints, y=design.lower.bound))+
  geom_point(checkpoints_data,mapping= aes(x=checkpoints, y=design.upper.bound))
```

This is what I get instead of having the two areas completely filled. Also colors are not respected by ggplot and I don't understand why:

**plot image**

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your coordinates incorrect in the `polygon_data` data frame. `c(650, 1625, 3250, 650, 1625, 3250)` should be `c(650, 1625, 3250, 3250, 1625, 650)`

Try this:

```
polygon_data <- data.frame(checkpoints = c(650, 1625, 3250, 3250, 1625, 650),
                           lower = c(-1.17, 0.20, 1.36, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf),
                           upper = c(2.28, 1.75, 1.36, Inf, Inf, Inf))
```

Maybe it is also a good idea to put the `alpha` parameter outside `aes()`. This avoids getting an extra legend. The legend of `fill` also looks a bit weird. Maybe it is also a good idea to place `fill` outside `aes()`.

Comment: Thanks! it did the job